# On hover of any element how can I select all sibling elements using CSS3 selector?

Tags: css

Consider below given HTML.

```
<ul class="chars_container">
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
   <li>E</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.chars_container{
    list-style-type: none
}

.chars_container li{
    float : left ;
    margin: 20px ;
    font-size : 50px;
    color : #f00;
}

.chars_container li:hover ~ li{
       color : #0f0; 
}
```

On hover of any 'li' I want to change color property of all sibling 'li'. I am using ~ selector which is selecting only next all siblings.

Please visit this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dFm9H/) for the same code.

Comment: You can't do this using pure CSS3, just use script for this. Maybe you will be able to do this in CSS4 which is still in draft mode.

Comment: @vals I'm the one who should say sorry, I did not know about your age before posting the previous comments, you're as old as my father (hope your profile is true) so I should have been respectful to you no matter what your comment was. There also might be some misunderstanding relating to the difference between languages here. Never mind about it :)

Comment: Yes, my profile is true. Never mind, have I nice day :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wish to have something like <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/dFm9H/4/)**</kbd>

css

```
.chars_container:hover > li{
       color : #0f0; 
}
.chars_container li:hover {
       color : #f00; 
}
```

or

```
.chars_container:hover li{
       color : #0f0; 
}
.chars_container li:hover {
       color : #f00; 
}
```